# How to delete all lines with 2 periods across multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, command

I have about 300 text files, each of them contains a list of domains.

I'm trying to remove all domains that have 2 periods in them.  For example, here's one list:

```
example.com
stackoverflow.com
google.co.uk
testing.com
another.something.whatever
google.com
```

That list should become this:

```
example.com
stackoverflow.com
testing.com
google.com
```

The domains `google.co.uk` and `another.something.whatever` should be deleted since they contain more than one period.

I know I can grep for all those lines like this:

```
grep "\..*\." *.txt
```

I wasn't able to find any previous questions about deleting lines with more than one symbol across multiple files.  If I missed it and this is a duplicate, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

And of course I figured it out right after posting the question.

This is what worked for me:

```
sed -i '' '/\..*\./d' *.txt
```

I originally tried this but it wouldn't work on Mac:

```
sed -i '/\..*\./d' *.txt
```

Comment: Or, you can invert your grep search: `grep -v '[.].*[.]'`